# Plotly Heatmap clickData

Tags: python, events, click, heatmap, plotly-dash

I have a heatmap made using `plotly.graph_objects.Heatmap`.  I'm now designing a dash app, which should have the heatmap and a separate text box or graph displaying some data associated with a given heatmap cell.  I would like the text box/graph to update based on which cell was last clicked by the user.

Can someone tell me how to access the 'clicked cell data' for a given heatmap cell?  I think the equivalent for a graph (which I've seen mentioned elsewhere in answers to similar questions) is `dcc.Graph.clickData`, but I can't see a `clickData` attribute for `go.heatmap`.

Thanks!
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was provided by Yanboe here:  https://community.plotly.com/t/heatmap-clickdata/66245?u=timothyk